# what does "linker input file unused because linking not done" means

Tags: c, makefile, linker

hi im trying to create a shared object for my native library to be accessed by my java project but when i run the makefile i get the error unable to link
here's my makefile

```
LIB_FILE = ../lib/libpktartintf.so
SRCS := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)


CC = gcc
INCFLAGS = -I../include
CFLAGS += $(INCFLAGS) -Wall -MMD -MP
LDFLAGS = -shared
$(LIB_FILE): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) -c $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -f *.o *.d $(LIB_FILE)


-include $(DEPS)
```

when I "make" it im getting the following error

```
 gcc -c -shared -I../include -Wall -MMD -MP -o ../lib/libpktartintf.so pktartintf.o
 gcc: warning: pktartintf.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

any idea why

Comment: `gcc -c` means no linking is done. `-shared -o libpktartintf.so` on the other hands suggests you want to link stuff into that shared object. The compiler warns you about that ...

Comment: Another way of putting it - why do you have `-c` in our command? Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: i'm a newbie in makefile , when I remove -c I get error: /usr/bin/ld: pktartintf.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Comment: The error message seems clear enough... you need to `"recompile with -fPIC"`.